# Hide siteMapNode when at particular view

Tags: asp.net, .net, web.sitemap

I have siteMapNode inside SiteMap in Web.sitemap and want to hide one of the menu items, when I am at the page .../example.aspx?title=hiding

I tried to hide that menu from example.aspx.cs at Page_Load with smth like:

```
MenuItemCollection menuItems = Menu.Items;
MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
foreach (MenuItem item in menuItems)
{ 
if (item.Text == "home") 
     menuItem = item; 
} 
menuItems.Remove(menuItem);
```

but I couldn't find needed item. Also I have tried to add logic into `MenuTop_MenuItemDataBound`, but it isn't executing at every url change

Comment: Share the code which you have tried so far, to get help faster....

Comment: I tried to hide that menu from example.aspx.cs at Page_Load with smth like:
`MenuItemCollection menuItems = Menu.Items;
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
        foreach (MenuItem item in menuItems) {
         if (item.Text == "home")
          menuItem = item;
        }
        menuItems.Remove(menuItem);`
but I couldn't find needed item.

Also I have tried to add logic into MenuTop_MenuItemDataBound, but it isn't executing at every url change